# What is the origin of Zoe (ζωή) vs Psyche (ψυχή) life in St. John?

Tags: john-apostle, eternal-life

It seems in John's gospel and and in other letters by John, there is a big theological emphasis on the difference between (in the Greek) ζωή "Zoe" life and ψυχή "Psyche" life.

> **[John 12:25](http://bible.cc/john/12-25.htm) (NIV)**
>   **25** The man who loves his life [ψυχή / Psyche] will lose it, while the man who hates his life [ψυχή / Psyche] in this world will keep it for eternal life [ζωή / Zoe].

Is there any evidence of this idea preceding Christ, in Jewish thought up to that point, or in other religious traditions or is this unique to Christianity?

Answer (score 5):

Aristotle (384-322 BC) talked about *zoe* versus *psyche* in his treatise [*De Anima* ("On the Soul")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Soul).  However, his concept of the mortal and immortal components of the complete human is a bit different than our current understanding.

An excerpt from [the Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09238c.htm) discusses this:

> For Aristotle, in the case of living natural bodies the vital principle, *psyche* is the form. His doctrine is embodied in his famous definition: *psyche estin entekexeia e prote somatos fysikou dynamei zoen exontos*. (De Anima, II, i), i.e. the soul is therefore the first *entelechy* (substantial form or perfect actualization) of a natural or organized body potentially possessing life. The definition applies to plants, animals, and man.

That source goes on to say

> The human soul, however, seems to be of a different kind (*genos etepron*), and separable as the eternal from the perishable.

However, it should be noted that while Aristotle considers the *zoe* to be separable from the *psyche*, it's the *psyche* that is eternal, not the *zoe*:

per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Soul):

> Aristotle also argues that the mind (only the agent intellect) is immaterial, able to exist without the body, and immortal.

And also

> He holds that the soul is the form, or essence of any living thing; that it is not a distinct substance from the body that it is in; that it is the possession of soul (of a specific kind) that makes an organism an organism at all, and thus that the notion of a body without a soul, or of a soul in the wrong kind of body, is simply unintelligible.

finally

> Some commentators have suggested that Aristotle's term soul is better translated as *lifeforce*

Given this, I would have to say that yes, the concept that there is a mortal component and an eternal component to us all is an older concept the Christianity.  However, the concept isn't quite the same as our current understanding.